# How to change UIButton frame to fit the image inside in IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I have created a button in storyboard with an image. When highlighted(touched), I want this button to change image with a larger one and resize according to new image. Storyboard is set and here is my code for touch up inside event:

```
if(self.testButton.state == UIControlStateHighlighted)
{
    self.testButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 20, 120, 145);
    self.testButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
}
NSLog(@"End Frame: ( %f %f %f %f )", self.testButton.frame.origin.x, self.testButton.frame.origin.y, self.testButton.frame.size.width, self.testButton.frame.size.height );
```

but my frame size does not change. My question

1.Can I solve this with storyboard?
2.How can I solve this with code?

Comment: That can't be your actual code as it won't compile (for 2 reasons)...

Comment: sorry changed code too much.edited

Comment: So, is the code getting run (is your log printed out)?

Comment: not 100, 20, 120, 145

Comment: You know you can write `NSLog(@"End Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.testButton.frame);`

Comment: Consider, is the button supposed to still be highlighted when the user has released their touch?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Declare buttonFrame as instance variable and add targets.

```
CGRect buttonFrame;

[self.testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)touchDown
{
    buttonFrame = self.testButton.frame;
    self.testButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.testButton.frame.origin.x, self.testButton.frame.origin.y, 120, 145);
    self.testButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
}

- (void)touchUp
{
    self.testButton.frame = buttonFrame;
}
```

Comment: This code won't compile either because you copied the errors in the code in the question.

Comment: yes of course I missed, you can't change size, but you can change frame. Code updated